# Length of implicit curve:

Tags: integration

How to find the length of the curve $(x^2+y^2)^3 = 4(x^2 + xy +y^2)^2$?
I have found an explicit polar form $r = 2-\cos(2\theta)$ by setting $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$. Now I can have a parametrization in $\theta$ but I can also use the derived formula for the length of a curve in explicit polar form: $$\int\sqrt{r(\theta)^2+r'(\theta)^2}\mathrm d\theta$$
However this doesn't seem to work, I can't reduce the square root to anything simpler.

Comment: Are you sure there is a nice answer? It seems that neither Maple nor WolframAlpha can evaluate the integral algebraically.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think that you made a small mistake since, if I am correct,
$$r(\theta)=2+\sin(2\theta)$$
Now, using

$$L=\int\sqrt{r(\theta)^2+r'(\theta)^2}\, d\theta$$ and simplifying, you end with the monster
$$L=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\int {\sqrt{8 \sin (2 t)+3 \cos (4 t)+13}}\, d\theta$$ which,as Milten commented, is far away to be pleasant. So, numerical integration seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Okay thanks, i'll try numeric integration.